# Checkbox named by string and variable. Trouble getting VBScript to recognize it as an object

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

Modified Code.
Error message: `Object required:'document.getElementsByName(...)(...)'`
Line:59
Char:13
Code with Error: `if document.getElementsByName("chk" & arrName(ii))(0).Checked then`

```
<SCRIPT language="VBScript">
Dim arrName(),arrExe()

Set objFS   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile("software/software.txt")
strSoftware = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

arrSplit = Split(strSoftware, vbNewLine)

i = 0

For Each strLine in arrSplit
  ReDim Preserve arrName(i + 1)
  ReDim Preserve arrExe(i + 1)
  arrName(i) = TRIM(Left(strLine,InStr(strLine,";")-1))
  arrExe(i) = TRIM(Right(strLine,InStr(strLine,";")))
  strHTML = CheckboxArea.InnerHTML
  strHTML = strHTML & "<BR><INPUT TYPE='CHECKBOX' VALUE='" & arrName(i) & "' NAME ='chk'" & arrName(i) & " />" & arrName(i)
  CheckboxArea.InnerHTML = strHTML
  i = i + 1
Next

Sub Confirm
    Dim objForm, Element
    set objForm=document.forms("SoftwareSelect")
    set Element=objForm.elements
    i=0
    ii=0

    for i=0 to Element.length
        if Element(i).type="checkbox" then
            if document.getElementsByName("chk" & arrName(ii))(0).Checked then 
                MsgBox(arrName(ii) & " is checked.")
            end if
        ii = ii + 1
        end if
    next
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Is it out of intent that you don't use ' or " to enclose the attribute values? Shouldn't it be better that way: `"<br /><input type='checkbox' value='" & arrName(i) & "' name='chk'" & arrName(i) & " />" & arrName(i)`
And what does arrName(i) contain?

Comment: I didn't bother because the checkboxes were being drawn fine, but I did just add them.  Didn't do anything for my problem though.  I feel like it's because I ReDim'd my arrays but I used preserve so they should still have their values..  If I'm not mistaken, arrays that are Dim'd on the <Script> level should be able to be used in all Subs within that script, correct?

Comment: Remains the question for arrName. Where is it defined and what does it contain?

Comment: It is defined at the beginning of the <script> and it holds a string value assigned by a loop.  I'll add it to the OP.

Comment: Well it could be that the string value you use, is not an accepted attribute for input and therefore the input is invalid. Does it work with this: `"<br /><label for='chk" & i &"'><input id='chk" & i & "' type='checkbox' value='" & arrName(i) & "' name='chk' />" & arrName(i) & "</label>"`?

Comment: Gives the same error.
The error is down at line 60 which is: `if "chk" & arrName(ii).Checked then`
Edit: Sorry, wrong line.

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot work. You say that arrName is an array of strings. A string is not a checkbox object. The solution is so near though.

Just look a bit above the code line. This should work, shouldn't it?

```
if Element(i).type="checkbox" then
    ii = ii + 1
    if "chk" & Element(i).Checked then 
        MsgBox(arrName(ii) & " is checked.")
    end if
end if
```

Comment: My plan was to use the string in the checkbox objects name, hence "chk" & string and then call on it later.

When you use a form's element (objForm.elements) the elements are identified by the names you assign them?  If that's the case then that code should work.  Maybe even without the "chk" correct?

Yup, that worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An expression like this:

```
"chk" & arrName(ii).Checked
```

will first try to get the value of the `Checked` property of an object stored in field `ii` of array `arrName` before concatenating that value to the string `"chk"`. What you actually mean to do is get the element with the name `"chk" & arrName(ii)` and then get the value of the `Checked` property of that element. Try this:

```
If document.getElementsByName("chk" & arrName(ii))(0).Checked Then
  ...
```

- `"chk" & arrName(ii)` is the value of the `name` attribute identifying the element you want to obtain.
- `document.getElementsByName(...)` returns a collection of all elements whose `name` attribute has that value.
- `...(0).Checked` selects the first element from that collection and returns the value of its `Checked` property.

As a side note: you may want to use the `id` attribute instead of the `name` attribute for identifying elements in a page, because that attribute by definition must be unique in a page. That way you could directly retrieve a particular element via `getElementById()` and won't have to deal with fiddling it out of a collection first.

**Edit:** If you want to iterate over all checkboxes in the page, something like this might be more suitable:

```
For Each tag In document.getElementsByTagName("input")
  If LCase(tag.Type) = "checkbox" Then
    'do stuff
  End If
Next
```

Comment: How would that line change if I used `getElementById()`?

Comment: I'm getting an error: "`Object required:'document.getElementsByName(...)(...)`" with that line.

Comment: Like I already said, it would loop over all elements whose `name` attribute has the given value. If you want to iterate over all checkboxes you need to use `getElementsByTagName("input")` and process all elements with type `checkbox` in that collection. `getElementById()` is only useful when you want to select one particular element.

Comment: @Meltdown Without more context that error message is useless. I'm not psychic. What are the values inside the parentheses? Please update your question with your modified code.

Comment: Posted the modified code.  All I changed was adding the line you suggested

Comment: `Element(i)` already is what you're looking for. You don't need my code there. This should suffice: `If Element(i).type="checkbox" Then : If Element(i).Checked Then : MsgBox Element(i).name & " is checked." : End If : End If`